# Load rows faster from DB

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have the following code:

```
 let
    
        Source = AnalysisServices.Databases("external\database", [TypedMeasureColumns=true, Implementation="2.0"]),
    
        ProfiBI = Source{[Name="DB"]}[Data],
    
        Profi1 = ProfiBI{[Id="DBFolder"]}[Data],
    
        Profi2 = Profi1{[Id="DBFolder2"]}[Data],
    
        #"Added Items" = Cube.Transform(Name2,
    
            {
    
                {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "[Calendar]", {"[Calendar].[Month Name].[Month Name]", "[Calendar].[Week No Retail].[Week No Retail]", "[Calendar].[Year No Retail].[Year No Retail]"}, {"Calendar.Month Name", "Calendar.Week No Retail", "Calendar.Year No Retail"}},
    
                {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "[Merchandise Structure]", {"[Merchandise Structure].[Level 02 Desc EN].[Level 02 Desc EN]"}, {"Merchandise Structure.Level 02 Desc EN"}},
    
                {Cube.AddAndExpandDimensionColumn, "[Sites]", {"[Sites].[Area Director].[Area Director]", "[Sites].[Opening Date].[Opening Date]", "[Sites].[Opening Year].[Opening Year]", "[Sites].[Regional Director].[Regional Director]", "[Sites].[Site Name].[Site Name]", "[Sites].[Site No].[Site No]", "[Sites].[Site Type 02].[Site Type 02]"}, {"Sites.Area Director", "Sites.Opening Date", "Sites.Opening Year", "Sites.Regional Director", "Sites.Site Name", "Sites.Site No", "Sites.Site Type 02"}},
    
                {Cube.AddMeasureColumn, "Sales Net Amt AY", "[Measures].[Sales Net Amt AY]"}
    
            }),
    
        #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Items", each [Sites.Opening Year] = "2020"),
    
        #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each (Cube.AttributeMemberId([Calendar.Year No Retail]) = "[Calendar].[Year No Retail].&[2020]" meta [DisplayName = "2020"])),
    
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"Sites.Site No", Int64.Type}, {"Sites.Opening Year", type date}, {"Sites.Opening Date", type date}, {"Calendar.Year No Retail", type date}, {"Calendar.Week No Retail", Int64.Type}})
    
    in
    
        #"Changed Type"
```

When the query runs it will load 92785 rows, but the problem is I have to wait 5-7 minutes for that. Is there a way to load rows faster into my table? Also is checked Add to Data Model.

Everything works as it should be, but it takes too slow to load data. Data is retrieved from an OLAP Cube. I'm new with PowerQuery so please, I need help.

Thanks!

Comment: OLAP cubes really don't like being shredded into transactions. Why not connect directly to the cube? Is it SSAS? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-ssas-multidimensional

Comment: exactly like this is connected

Comment: if I connect through Analysis Server it will create an ODC file, but I can create only PivotTables or PivotCharts and it works pretty fast. To that data, I need to add some columns that are not in the cube, and based on those, build some formulas and get some %.

Comment: If you want better performance I suggest you add those columns to the cube or write MDX that calms them on the fly. MDX is SSAS query language.

Comment: I don't have access to add data to the cube and as I said, I'm new with power query so maybe you have some time and can help me with MDX writing. thanks!